# JS file (drupal.behaviors) that does some simple jQuery works for anon users but not authenticated?

Tags: javascript

I have an issue where a JS file I've included with my theme using the .info file works for anonymous users but not authenticated. It has a unique namespace and using the debugger, the contents of the function are skipped when logged in. Here is my JS file:

```
Drupal.behaviors.wet4_ctasidebar = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
        alert("it works");
        $(window).resize(function(){
            if ($('.container').innerWidth() <= 751){
                $('#sidebar-aside').detach().insertAfter('.node-body');
            } else if ($('.container').innerWidth() >=752){
                $('#sidebar-aside').detach().prependTo('.node-body');
            }
        })
        if ($('.container').innerWidth() <= 751){
            $('#sidebar-aside').detach().insertAfter('.node-body');
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Could it be there is some Javascript error when logged in that's causing Drupal's JS to break?

Comment: I wish. There were no errors, it just refused to run inside my function.